# How do I embed Java test method as an example into my markdown documentation using Znai

Tags: java, markdown, documentation, znai

I have a test class `MyExamplesTest` with examples of how to use my API.
How can I use the examples inside my documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Use [include-java](https://testingisdocumenting.org/znai/snippets/java) extension.

```
Example of `myApi` usage:

:include-java: com/example/MyExamplesTest.java {
  title: "example",
  entry: "testMethodName",
  bodyOnly: true
}
```